# How would the linear regression model look like?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Typically I see $y$ as the response variable and $x$ as the predictor variable.
$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i,\quad i=1,\dots,n.$$

What other forms can the equation have? Would it be valid if we omit the $\epsilon$, for example:  $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+β_2x_i?$

What if we don't include all  $\beta$'s and $x$'s? Or should we raise them to some power: $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+ \beta_2*(x^2) + \beta5*(x^5)+\epsilon?$

Comment: Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc). Also, it might be worthwhile to research the "underlying assumptions" section of the regression analysis article in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).

Comment: $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+\beta_2 x_i = \beta_0+(\beta_1+\beta_2) x_i$, so the extra parameter isn't useful. $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i+ \beta_2 x_i^2 +\ldots+ \beta_5 x_i^5 +\epsilon_i$ is a polynomial regression.